# Jmeter webui fails to record

Tags: jmeter-5.0

I have been trying to setup my test environment for Jmeter recording with WebUI. I had followed all the steps as mentioned in the guide i.e. proxy server setting and uploaded certificate in browser as well. I starting jmeter through command prompt

```
jmeter -H my.proxy.server -P 80 -u username -a Password -N localhost
```

When I record anything with these settings jmeter doesn't record anything and the log shows no error. Logs read Start recording and stop recording. But nothing gets recorded/captured

What can be the root cause of the problem?
1. I need to talk to support team to open some settings?
2. I am using my company proxy server name with port 80

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Could you add the Proxy Scheme to use parameter (**-E https**) when you start the JMeter?
2. Could you stop the JMeter Proxy (HTTPS Test Script Recorder) and check if you can access the application through the web browser? If you can access the application when proxy is stopped then you will have to configure (recheck) the browser's proxy settings.
3. If you get error  proxy not found error on your browser then your browser is trying to access the application through the proxy.

   3.1 Can you check if you have set HTTPS Domains in HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder 
   [image]

   3.2 Have you set any request filtering? Could you remove all the request filtering and give a try?
   [image]

   3.3 Trust your certificate if not expired. Default vapidity period of the certificate is 7 days. Create a new certificate and reinstall it on your browser.